# Is there a way to change Kibana's default data path

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

Kibana being installed, I'm trying now to configure it correctly. I have a question : is there a way to modify Kibana's default data path. For example, you can modify log path by changing logging.dest var value within the file "/etc/kibana/kibana.yml" but this file doesn't contain any var for changing data path. I already looked within their official documentation but I found nothing...

In the meantime, if you have any advices concerning Kibana's installation and configuring, I'm totally listening...

Thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: Which data? Elasticsearch data?

Comment: @Lax Kibana's own data, the documentation tells that Kibana's default data path is /var/lib/kibana/ and I want to change this path...

Answer (score 1):

Can do that by updating the "path.data" value in the config file "kibana.yml"

```
path.data: "new path for data"
```

location for config file is /etc/kibana/kibana.yml for rpm install for tar/zip install it will be in config folder.

Answer (score 0):

DATA_PATH=/data   /opt/kibana-5.2.0/bin/kibana